# Accessing 'Other Users'

Tags: macos, hard-drive, spotlight

When I look at 'About this Mac/Storage' nearly half of my hard disk (120GB) is taken by 'Other Users'.  I am the only person using this MacBook (OSX 12.6.5) and I have no memory of creating any other accounts!

How can I see these 'Other Users' accounts and files?  I want to know what they are and either copy them to my normal account or delete them.

I also wonder If I can merge the two users (deleting one in the process?)

Comment: Since posting this question I have established that I have  two accounts on my MacBook (OSX 12.6.5). 

Is it possible to merge these two accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Apple is rather opaque about how it defines its categories in the Storage breakdown (and some rely on accurate Spotlight indexing).

On my Mac (Sonoma), it says "**Other Users & Shared**", which covers all the folders under `/Users`, including `/Users/Shared`. Some apps put content in that folder.

[image]

On my Mac running Ventura, it doesn't say "& Shared", but the size does tally with the contents of `/Users/Shared`.

You can always do **Get Info** on any folder under `/Users`, to see how much data there is. Some utilities that sort your disk by size, such as OmniDiskSweeper, DaisyDisk and others, may or may not show you inside other users' folders; but they should at least show you the size.